# Push Notifications to Rocket.Chat in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, rocket.chat

I am trying to setup notifications to my Rocket.Chat server through my .gitlab-ci.yml file. I have my test and deploy stages working, but my notify stage is erroring out. I followed the instructions from [here](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/08/02/using-the-gitlab-ci-slash-cd-for-smart-home-configuration-management/), but I adjusted the notify scripts to work with Rocket.Chat instead of Pushbullet.

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy
  - notify

test:
  stage: test
  image: homeassistant/amd64-homeassistant
  script:
    - hass --script check_config -c .

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apk update && apk add openssh-client )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - ssh $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_HOST "cd '$DEPLOY_PATH'; git pull; sudo systemctl restart home-assistant@homeassistant"

notify_success:
  stage: notify
  allow_failure: true
  only:
    - master
  script: 
    - curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"text":"New Hass config deployed successfully!"}' https://chat.bryantgeeks.com/hooks/$ROCKET_CHAT_TOKEN

notify_fail:
  stage: notify
  allow_failure: true
  only:
    - master
  when: on_failure
  script: 
    - curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"text":"New Hass config failed. Please check for errors!"}' https://chat.bryantgeeks.com/hooks/$ROCKET_CHAT_TOKEN
```

I get this error in the CI Lint:

> Status: syntax is incorrect
>
> Error: jobs:notify_success:script config should be a string or an array of strings

If I change the notify script lines to have single quotes around it ('), I get the following error in CI Lint:

> Status: syntax is incorrect
>
> Error: (): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 33 column 7

If I try double quotes around the script line ("), I get the following error:

> Status: syntax is incorrect
>
> Error: (): did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection at line 33 column 5

I'm not sure what else to try or where to look at this point for how to correct this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAML really doesn't like `:`'s in strings. The culprit is the `:` in `'Content-Type: application/json'`

Sometimes using the multiline string format helps, like this:

```
notify_success:
  stage: notify
  allow_failure: true
  only:
    - master
  script: |
    curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"text":"New Hass config deployed successfully!"}' https://chat.bryantgeeks.com/hooks/$ROCKET_CHAT_TOKEN
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed it. I did have to add a before_script to install curl in the container for that stage.